# using rsync for 'cp -rl' is copying endlessly

Tags: rsync

I am using `cp -rl` to copy a folder tree and would like to get some information about the copy.
I was thinking about using rsync,
this is what I tried so far this, but without any success, it seems to copy endlessly:

```
rsync -ah --info=progress2 -rl src_dir dst_dir
```

`cp` is doing it in less than a minute, `rsync` was still on after 10 minutes...

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have put progress option in it, what does logs say on terminal of your server? Is it showing any error or information? Kindly do let us know, thank you.

Comment: it is not showing any error, it is copying more (over 1GB) than the target size (about 200MB). But the progress does not show any files so I don't know what is going on, thank you